# How to use mysql with Windows 10 UWP app

Tags: mysql, uwp, windows-10

I am trying to use mysql with a windows 10 UWP app. I am told everywhere to download connector/NET and to reference the Assemblies/rt MySql.Data.RT.dll. however after downloading every connector mysql's website has available I am unable to find this dll to reference. I have also tried every other dll that was installed and every one of them says "a reference to '' could not be added. `The project targets '.NETCore' while the file reference targets '.NETFramework'. this is not a supported scenario"` How can I use mysql with my new app? is this no longer possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in luck! If your app targets the **Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 16299)**, you can connect to external databases.

First problem you have to tackle is the fact that you cannot directly reference .NET Framework libraries from UWP apps. This can be circumvented by creating a .NET Standard library and referencing the .NET Framework libarary from there.

Unfortunately this **doesn't work with the official MySQL Connector yet** (due to some unsupported references), but there are alternatives. The ones that are the most promising are those that support .NET Standard. For example the [MySqlConnector project](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) offers a very similar interface to the official connector. It is still in beta, but is regularly updated and actively developed.

You can install it into your project very easily using NuGet. Open the NuGet package console (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console) and enter the following:

```
Install-Package MySqlConnector -Version 0.34.0
```

Now you can use `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand`, etc. as usual.

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=uwpconnect;port=3306;password=";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT Name FROM world";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
   sb.AppendLine(rdr[0].ToString());
}
rdr.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)?

Comment: @insane_developer : 6 weeks builing uwp app with dapper, no problem at debug time, but at compile time : Dynamic code generation is not supported on this platform... have to replace dapper in one day :(