# How to connect UWP to MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, uwp

I have a simple UWP app that communicates with MySQL. I am using MySqlConnector. Everything works fine in Debug mode. But after installing the application on (another) PC there is no connection with the database. I did everything as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131113/how-to-use-mysql-with-windows-10-uwp-app). As I understand it, the MySQL library is not copied into the project. What am I doing wrong?

```
using MySqlConnector;
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            LoadFromDB();
        }

        private void LoadFromDB()
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; database=database; username=root; password=pass;");
            MySqlCommand command;
            MySqlDataReader reader;

            connection.Open();
            command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Numbers", connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                myTextBlock.Text = reader["Num"].ToString();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I don't get an exception. The program just crashes. I also tried try-catch. It does not help. Can the cause of the error be that it is an Sideload-App?

Comment: you need the exception to understand your probleme, what you can do is to test the connection between your pc and server , i don't think that you are missing mysql library .

Comment: Thanks. I tested again in a new project. The following exception appears: Connect Timeout expired

Comment: When you move to another pc to connect to the database, Are the values of Server, Port, etc. empty in your LocalSettings? Is the connectionString correct?

Comment: Hi Faywang, thanks. I have checked connectionStrings. Everything is correct. I run the same code in WPF. It's works right.

Comment: To maintain security and network isolation, loopback connections for IPC are blocked by default for packaged applications. If you enable loopback connections, will the same issue occur? For more information about how to enable loopback connections, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication#loopback).

Comment: Faywang, thank you very much for your answer. Your tip helped me. Thanks. I had to enable loopback. Please post your tip as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain security and network isolation, loopback connections for IPC are blocked by default for packaged applications. You should enable loopback connections. For more information about how to enable loopback connections, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication#loopback)